# How to get browser history javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, browser

My browser history:
a.com => b.com ==> c.com

I'm stay at http://c.com page and how can I get value of previous history (a.com)?
I tried to use 
    **document.referrer**
but it returns "http://b.com"

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible, it would be a violation of user's privacy.

If you get both `a.com` and `b.com` to agree you can track the user using a cookie, but a lot of user agents (browsers) send do-not-track headers and block third party cookies.

You can ask the user though.

Comment: Thanks! 
One more thing about this: The browser cannot give me previous history (use document.referrer ) when i clicked on a link in IFrame. Any idea?

Comment: That's a security feature.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to view history programatically, you should need browser plugins.

For example,

Chrome browser plugins:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history

Mozilla browser plugins:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Is there anyway to get history without browser plugins? Because I need to support IE too

Comment: Try this, May be it'll help you: http://tutorials.stevenyork.com/tutorial/getting_browser_history_using_javascript