# How to get browser history with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, browser-history

Is there any option to find with javascript does user previous visit sites like booking.com , expedia.com and similar OTA's and find that link to use it into website?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556781/can-we-get-browser-history-by-using-javascript

Comment: Privacy issues mate, you can't collect my history or from other users with JS

Comment: But is there any hack to know does user visit booking.com before come to my hotel website ?

Comment: @AleksPer That's a _slightly_ different question - are you wanting to know if they've clicked a link and ended up on your site directly?  Not that they've _ever_ been on a particular site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get browser history javascript/Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089783/how-to-get-browser-history-javascript-jquery)

Comment: You can make use of the `Referer` HTTP header to see what site linked to your site. But this only works if they link directly from that site to yours. That is pretty much the most you can get.